# Video inside a bare CSS modal window autostarting before modal window is opened

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement a video inside a bare CSS modal window as instructed [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) and it works great so far. The only problem I get is that video autostarts before modal window is even opened (I have to keep the video "autostart" option). Also video doesn't stop when modal window is closed.

Are there any CSS/HTML solutions for this? If there aren't any CSS/HTML solutions to this you can help me with javascript solutions.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.boxspace {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 16.6666%;
    padding-bottom: 16.6666%;
}
.boxInner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    right: 2%;
    top: 2%;
    bottom: 2%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: thin solid #969696;
    border-radius: 4%;
}
.boxInner img {
    width: 100%;
}
.boxInner .titleBox {
    position: absolute;

    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin-bottom: -42%;
    background: #000000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.boxInner .titleBox header{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
 }
.boxInner .titleBox p{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.0vw;
 }
body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.modalVideo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
} 
.modalVideo:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalVideo > div {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2vw;
    margin-left: 20vw;
    margin-right: 20vw;
    padding-top: 1vw;
    padding-bottom: 1vw;
    padding-left:1.05vw;
    padding-right:1.05vw;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
}
.modalVideo video {
    width: 100%;
}
.modalProgram {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
} 
.modalProgram:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalProgram > div {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2vw;
    margin-left: 10vw;
    margin-right: 10vw;
    padding-top: 1vw;
    padding-bottom: 1vw;
    padding-left:2vw;
    padding-right:2vw;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
}
.close {
    background: #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4vw;
    right: -4.2vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left:0.75vw;
    padding-right:0.75vw;
    padding-bottom:0.25vw;
    padding-top:0.25vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0vw;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0vw;
    border-top-right-radius: 1vw;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1vw;
}
.close:hover { 
    background: #464646; 
}
```

```html
<body class="no-touch"> 

    <div class="boxspace">

        <!-- tiles: -->     
        <div class="box">
            <div class="boxInner">
                <img src="http://dominicm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/steam-arch-linux.png" />
                <div class="titleBox">
                    <header>
                    Linux/C/ARM
                    </header>
                    <p>
                    <a href="#linux-c-arm_video">video</a><br>                  
                    <a href="#linux-c-arm_program">program</a><br>
                    prijavnica
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of tiles and wrap -->
    
    <!--Linux/C/ARM - program-->
    <div id="linux-c-arm_program" class="modalProgram">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">close</a>
                <h3>HEADER</h3>
                <p>
                    Paragraph
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--Linux/C/ARM - video-->
    <div id="linux-c-arm_video" class="modalVideo">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">close</a>
            <video controls autoplay>
                <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    
 
    <!-- end "no-touch" parameter for body--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        // See if this is a touch device
        if ('ontouchstart' in window){
            // Set the correct [touchscreen] body class
            $('body').removeClass('no-touch').addClass('touch');
            // Add the touch toggle to show text when tapped
            $('div.boxInner img').click(function(){
                $(this).closest('.boxInner').toggleClass('touchFocus');
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
    
</body>
```

Comment: can you explain _why_ you need to keep the video autostart option?

Comment: From the answers it looks like I don't need it - now javascript will take care of that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this can't be done by HTML or CSS.

But you could easily do it with JavaScript and since you already have some jQuery code I'd recommend doing it also with jQuery because in this case you could easily achieve this by adding the following part to your script

**jQuery**

```
var $video = $(".modalVideo video")[0];
$video.autoplay = false;

$("a[href='#linux-c-arm_video']").click(function(){
  $video.play();
});

$(".close").click(function(){
  $video.pause();
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  // See if this is a touch device
  if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    // Set the correct [touchscreen] body class
    $('body').removeClass('no-touch').addClass('touch');
    // Add the touch toggle to show text when tapped
    $('div.boxInner img').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.boxInner').toggleClass('touchFocus');
    });
  }
});

var $video = $(".modalVideo video")[0];
$video.autoplay = false;

$("a[href='#linux-c-arm_video']").click(function() {
  $video.play();
});

$(".close").click(function() {
  $video.pause();
  $video.currentTime = 0;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.boxspace {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 16.6666%;
  padding-bottom: 16.6666%;
}
.boxInner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  right: 2%;
  top: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: thin solid #969696;
  border-radius: 4%;
}
.boxInner img {
  width: 100%;
}
.boxInner .titleBox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: -42%;
  background: #000000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.boxInner .titleBox header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
}
.boxInner .titleBox p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
}
body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox,
body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.modalVideo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalVideo:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalVideo > div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  margin-right: 20vw;
  padding-top: 1vw;
  padding-bottom: 1vw;
  padding-left: 1.05vw;
  padding-right: 1.05vw;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}
.modalVideo video {
  width: 100%;
}
.modalProgram {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalProgram:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalProgram > div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  padding-top: 1vw;
  padding-bottom: 1vw;
  padding-left: 2vw;
  padding-right: 2vw;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}
.close {
  background: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4vw;
  right: -4.2vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0.75vw;
  padding-right: 0.75vw;
  padding-bottom: 0.25vw;
  padding-top: 0.25vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0vw;
  border-top-right-radius: 1vw;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1vw;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #464646;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="no-touch">

  <div class="boxspace">

    <!-- tiles: -->
    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <img src="http://dominicm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/steam-arch-linux.png" />
        <div class="titleBox">
          <header>
            Linux/C/ARM
          </header>
          <p>
            <a href="#linux-c-arm_video">video</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#linux-c-arm_program">program</a>
            <br>prijavnica
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of tiles and wrap -->

  <!--Linux/C/ARM - program-->
  <div id="linux-c-arm_program" class="modalProgram">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">close</a>
      <h3>HEADER</h3>
      <p>
        Paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Linux/C/ARM - video-->
  <div id="linux-c-arm_video" class="modalVideo">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">close</a>
      <video controls autoplay>
        <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

### **More videos**

If you want the ability to have multiple videos which are called dynamically on click by a specific id you have to make following changes

At first I would recommend to exclude the video manipulation `play()`, `pause()` to a function called `playVideo()` for example.

**Function**

```
function playVideo(id) {
  var $video = $(id + " video")[0];
  $video.autoplay = false;
  $video.play();

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $video.pause();
    $video.currentTime = 0;
  });
}
```

Important to notice is that with this suggestion the function needs a parameter id. This will be the id of the link you clicked on. This works since the href of the link has the same id as the container of the video.

And finally to get the id only of the links a video should be displayed you have to add this to your code.

```
$(".box a[href*='video']").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("href");
  playVideo(id);
});
```

```js
   $(function() {
     // See if this is a touch device
     if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
       // Set the correct [touchscreen] body class
       $('body').removeClass('no-touch').addClass('touch');
       // Add the touch toggle to show text when tapped
       $('div.boxInner img').click(function() {
         $(this).closest('.boxInner').toggleClass('touchFocus');
       });
     }
   });

   $(".box a[href*='video']").click(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr("href");
     playVideo(id);
   });

   function playVideo(id) {
     var $video = $(id + " video")[0];
     $video.autoplay = false;
     $video.play();

     $(".close").click(function() {
       $video.pause();
       $video.currentTime = 0;
     });
   }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.boxspace {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 16.6666%;
  padding-bottom: 16.6666%;
}
.boxInner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  right: 2%;
  top: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: thin solid #969696;
  border-radius: 4%;
}
.boxInner img {
  width: 100%;
}
.boxInner .titleBox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: -42%;
  background: #000000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.boxInner .titleBox header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
}
.boxInner .titleBox p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
}
body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox,
body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.modalVideo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalVideo:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalVideo > div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  margin-right: 20vw;
  padding-top: 1vw;
  padding-bottom: 1vw;
  padding-left: 1.05vw;
  padding-right: 1.05vw;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}
.modalVideo video {
  width: 100%;
}
.modalProgram {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalProgram:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalProgram > div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  padding-top: 1vw;
  padding-bottom: 1vw;
  padding-left: 2vw;
  padding-right: 2vw;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}
.close {
  background: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4vw;
  right: -4.2vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0.75vw;
  padding-right: 0.75vw;
  padding-bottom: 0.25vw;
  padding-top: 0.25vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0vw;
  border-top-right-radius: 1vw;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1vw;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #464646;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="no-touch">

  <div class="boxspace">

    <!-- tiles: -->
    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <img src="http://dominicm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/steam-arch-linux.png" />
        <div class="titleBox">
          <header>
            Linux/C/ARM
          </header>
          <p>
            <a href="#linux-c-arm_video">video</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#linux-c-arm_program">program</a>
            <br>prijavnica
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <img src="http://dominicm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/steam-arch-linux.png" />
        <div class="titleBox">
          <header>
            Linux/Eagle/ARM
          </header>
          <p>
            <a href="#linux-eagle_video">video</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#linux-eagleprogram">program</a>
            <br>prijavnica
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of tiles and wrap -->

  <!--Linux/C/ARM - program-->
  <div id="linux-c-arm_program" class="modalProgram">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">close</a>
      <h3>HEADER</h3>
      <p>
        Paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Linux/C/ARM - video-->
  <div id="linux-c-arm_video" class="modalVideo">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">close</a>
      <video controls autoplay>
        <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="linux-eagle_video" class="modalVideo">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">close</a>
      <video controls autoplay>
        <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Would I need to swap `$video.pause();` for `$video.stop();` if I wanted video to stop after clicking on close? One more question. Is it better to write javascript or use JQuerry in terms of long term support?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `stop()` method defined. See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp). But you could simply add `$video.currentTime = 0;` after the `pause()` method. This sets the video play position to the beginning. You could also do a `$video.load()` instead. This will reload the entire video. Updated the snippet

Comment: And one more question. How would I make this work for more videos with ids `#linux-c-arm_video`, `linux-eagle_video` etc

Comment: Personally I would go for jQuery if you can. jQuery has such a huge community and I think it will exist for a very very long time because there was a reason this framework was developed. To simplify the coding with JavaScript. So I think it doesn't matter which way you will choose but with jQuery you even have the additional benefits for example the selector. Instead of the long `document.getElementById` you can simply do it with a `$("mydiv, class, id and many more")` which guarantees a much cleaner and more readable code at the end and everything is also very well documented.

Comment: Added a possible solution with a new snippet regarding to your question with multiple videos .

Comment: Somehow your answer works online as a code snippet, but when I download it it stops working.

Comment: Could you please say what actually isn't working. If in general no jQuery code is fired make sure that you have included the jQuery library correctly either in the `head` or before the `body` end tag

Comment: I am still searching for the error. Haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: Thanks to @andi I found the mistake. I had to remove autoplay option from videos and now it works...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no way to control the HTML video player with CSS.
And with HTML you cannot tell the video to start/stop when the modal is opened/closed, this is what javascript is for.

To controll the Video with js you could use plain javascript on modal open:

```
document.getElementById('videoId').play();
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this into my code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

### HTML Changes

Remove the `autoplay` attribute from the video elements—you don't actually want it to play when the page loads, you want it to play when the modal window opens.

### jQuery changes

Change your jQuery code to the following:

```
$(function(){
  // See if this is a touch device
  if ('ontouchstart' in window){
      // Set the correct [touchscreen] body class
      $('body').removeClass('no-touch').addClass('touch');
      // Add the touch toggle to show text when tapped
      $('div.boxInner img').click(function(){
          $(this).closest('.boxInner').toggleClass('touchFocus');
      });
  }

  /////////////////////////
  // Changes start here
  /////////////////////////

  // Play clicked video
  var playClickedVideo = function () {
    var videoId = $(this).attr('href');
    var video = $(videoId + ' video')[0];
    video.play();
  };

  $('.titleBox a').click(playClickedVideo);


  // Pause video when the close button is clicked
  var stopVideos = function () {
    $('video').each(function (i, video) {
      video.pause();
      video.currentTime = 0; // To rewind (optional)
    });
  };

  $('.close').click(stopVideos);

});
```

I have a CodePen demo here: http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/gLvwyy

I had to modify some of your CSS to see the links so I can click them, so only copy the jQuery.